# laravel request returns input as array key name with null value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, httprequest

I have a form that sends a request through Ajax in laravel
This snippet from my controller returns **null**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class StatusController extends Controller {
  public function postStatus(Request $request) {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
      dd($request->input('statusBody'));
```

This however returns an array with `statusBody` as a key name with null value

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class StatusController extends Controller {
  public function postStatus(Request $request) {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
      dd($request->input());
```

This is the returned result

```
array:1 [▼
  "This_is_a_sample_status" => null
]
```

And this **finally** returns the correct value

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class StatusController extends Controller {
  public function postStatus(Request $request) {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
      $val = $request->input('statusBody');
      dd(array_search($val, $request->all()));
```

My question is: Why does this happen?
Why doesn't `$request->input('name')` returns a value as expected?
**UPDATE:**
This is also the Ajax function which **successfully** logs the wanted result to the console

```
var statusBody = $('#statusBody').val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'status',
        data: statusBody,
        success: function(data){
          console.log(statusBody);
        }
      });
```

Comment: Could you update the question with the json/ajax code block? Normally, i think it should be ok using `$request->input('name');`

Comment: I have updated my question @AntonisTsimourtos even though I don't see how it relates as long as it passes the data to the controller and successfully logs the wanted result to the console

Comment: Try changing `data: statusBody,` to `data: statusBody.serialize(),` . Maybe adding `dataType: 'json',` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the problem in a fresh laravel app where I found out what's wrong.
`data` parameter in the Ajax function expects a dataString like so

```
var statusBody = $('#status').val();
      var dataString = "status="+statusBody;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'status',
        data: dataString
      });
```

Thanks to Antonis to point out the Ajax call